# Specific Cases of IOExceptions

Tags: java, exception

What can I do to make my code throw an `IOException`?

I have tried reading from and writing to a file that does not exist. But that throws a `FileNotFoundException`.

What are some specific things that throw an `IOException`?

Comment: Well, other any other IO problems. For example, what if the file is deleted while you're reading it? What if you try to read past the end of the stream? etc.

Comment: The class names of [known subclasses of `IOException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) should give you some hints as to the types of things that can go wrong.

Comment: EOF reading, Socket closed, access denied, ...

Comment: This question was in Triage, I've edited the problem statement to bring it in line with stackoverflow standards. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for an understanding of the way questions should be presented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to throw an `IOException()` deliberately, you should simply throw a new `IOException()` like so:

```
throw new IOException();
```

This is the correct way to deliberately throw an exception. Deliberately causing an exception to be thrown is not good practice, as it will make the exception look genuine.

Here is the full list of exception subclasses that can throw an `IOException()`:

```
ChangedCharSetException, CharacterCodingException, CharConversionException,
ClosedChannelException, EOFException, FileLockInterruptionException, 
FileNotFoundException, FilerException, FileSystemException, 
HttpRetryException, IIOException, InterruptedByTimeoutException, 
InterruptedIOException, InvalidPropertiesFormatException, 
JMXProviderException, JMXServerErrorException, MalformedURLException, 
ObjectStreamException, ProtocolException, RemoteException, SaslException, 
SocketException, SSLException, SyncFailedException, UnknownHostException, 
UnknownServiceException, UnsupportedDataTypeException, 
UnsupportedEncodingException, UserPrincipalNotFoundException, 
UTFDataFormatException, ZipException
```

This list is from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html.